# SQL - get minimum price based with date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database containing prices from various suppliers for the same product. Each supplier/product combination has a start & end date with a product ID and price

```
id | pid | aid | start_date | end_date | price
1  | 1   |  1  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-10 | 10.00
1  | 1   |  2  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-05 | 12.00
1  | 1   |  2  | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-09 | 9.00
```

I use a calendar table to make sure I have all the dates in a certain range.
The struggle I have is to select the min price given a certain date range. The above data should output as below.

```
date       | aid | price
2017-01-01 | 1   | 10.00
2017-01-02 | 1   | 10.00
2017-01-03 | 1   | 10.00
2017-01-04 | 1   | 10.00
2017-01-05 | 1   | 10.00
2017-01-06 | 2   |  9.00
2017-01-07 | 2   |  9.00
2017-01-08 | 2   |  9.00
2017-01-09 | 2   |  9.00
2017-01-10 | 1   | 10.00
```

Just having one supplier and getting the price is not an issue, but as soon as I start grouping the data I only get one result or an incorrect result.
I'm using this query, which provides the wrong outcome.

```
SELECT 
    c.date, min(p.price) as min_price 
FROM 
    bricks_calender c 
LEFT JOIN 
    bricks_prijzen p ON c.date BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date
WHERE 
    p.pid = 1 
GROUP BY 
    aid 
ORDER BY 
    c.date
```

Any suggestion where I need to update this query, to get the expected outcome? Or should I change my data model (which is of course not preferred)

Comment: Use group by aid and date

Comment: @RavinderReddy grouping by `aid` and `date` will give results exactly equal to the calendar table, as his dates are all different

Comment: @Ralf, can you provide what you are receiving as an "incorrect" output of your query?

Comment: In order to get the results you want, you would need another table with one row per date. This could be done with a temp table in a stored proc, or in php code. You would then join this with the table in your question, and use min() on the price to list the lowest price for each date.

Comment: I fiddled this for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/671ee9/1/0 . As expected, your above query outputs 2 rows, one for 10.00 and one for 9.00, so what is your intended results? How are you expecting it to be represented?

Comment: @sadmicrowave the intended result is the list of dates, having each date the minimum price available from the suppliers. Just two rows won't help, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Ralf, sorry but I don't fully understand what your are looking to accomplish yet.  Your explanation does not fully make sense.  `having each date the minimum price available from the supplier.` Isn't that what the calendar table represents already?  I'll ask again, can you provide a table or screenshot in your post that depicts what results you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bricks_calender contains one row per date, the follow should work:

```
SELECT 
    c.`date`, 
    (select s.`aid` from `bricks_prijzen` s where s.`price` = min(p.`price`) and c.`date` BETWEEN s.`start_date` AND s.`end_date` ORDER BY s.`price` ASC LIMIT 0,1) AS `aid`,
    min(p.`price`) as `min_price`
FROM `bricks_calender` c
LEFT JOIN `bricks_prijzen` p
    ON c.`date` BETWEEN p.`start_date` AND p.`end_date`
WHERE 
    p.`pid` = 1 
GROUP BY 
    c.`date`
ORDER BY 
    c.`date`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Two issues, the s.date field doesn't exists in the table bricks_prijzen. This table contains the start & end date field. Changing the section  "s.`date` = c.`date`" to "c.date between s.start_date and s.end_date" I get an error message 'comments out of sync'. Any other suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: I've updated the code. Sorry about that. I should have caught that the first time. As for the error message, are you sure it was "_comments_ out of sync" and not "_commands_ out of sync"?

Comment: @Ralf: I've created a SQL Fiddle to test the statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a220/2/0

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply because you group your data by `aid` with `GROUP BY aid`, so you can't have more row than the number of different `aid` that exist.

By unsetting this `GROUP BY`, does it solve the problem?